# How do I change the colors of the graph using dash plotly in python

Tags: python, graph, plotly-dash

I find a lot of examples of black graph sheets, with blue axis, but don't know how to do that. how do I do that?

this doesn't work:

```
chart01.update_layout(plot_bgcolor="#1c0d02")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plot_bgcolor** attribute sets the background color of the plotting area in-between x and y axes. So if you want to have your graph all in black you need to set the **paper_bgcolor** attribute too the dark color. This attribute sets the background color of the paper where the graph is drawn [see plotly layout](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-paper_bgcolor).

Or you can simply use plotly templates [Plotly built-in themes](https://plotly.com/python/templates/).
Here is an example using the plotly_dark template.

```
import plotly.express as px

# Use plotly_dark template
fig = px.line(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')

fig.show()
```